# Eclipse CDT: org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.text.CReconciler, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I can run Eclipse with CDT for about 15 minutes before it crashes with a java heap space out of memory error.  Its always associated with the `org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.text.CReconciler` thread.  It's gotten to the point where I'm running on auto pilot when it happens: "rm .lock", "y", "eclipse&" and away I go.  I can't find relevant information with the Google nor have I found a similar post on SO.  Anyone else run into this kind of issue before?

I'm using

Eclipse 3.6.1, Build ID: M20100909-0800
CDT 6.1
Subversion 2.2.1
Pydev 1.6.3.2

OS: Red Hat 2.16
Intel quad core machine, single monitor

I don't have root access.   I don't know what other information someone might need to help diagnose this.  IT person has tried to find more information but even he doesn't know what's going on.  This is not strictly an issue with just my computer either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you need more heap space than the default Eclipse setting provides.    Try launching Eclipse with 1G of heap by editing eclipse.ini and change the line starting with `-Xmx` to

```
-Xmx1024m
```

Alternatively you can launch from the command line with

```
eclipse -vmargs -Xmx1024m
```

[**UPDATE** - *probably should have been suggested first* ]

Tail the log file at `_<workspace>_/.metadata/.log` to see if there is any recurring event or error that might be leaking memory.

Comment: That seems to make it crash less.  Thanks.  Less often is better than all the time.